# Cómo hacer subcategorías en muchos niveles con PHP y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relaciones

Estoy con una duda. Tengo una tabla de categorías donde cada categoría puede tener una o mas subcategorías. Entonces lo que necesito es saber la formar de crear ese "árbol" de categorías de una forma sencilla si es que la hay.

Tengo lo siguiente en la DB:

```
 categories
------------------
(pk) | id
     | name
     | slug
     | image
(fk) | parent_id
```

Luego creo la relación en el modelo:

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this -> hasMany(Category::Class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

de esta manera traigo las categorías padres en el controlador:

```
$categories = Category::where('parent_id', NULL) -> orderBy('id', 'DESC') -> get();
```

y por último esto es lo que estoy haciendo y que me gustaría poder hacerlo de un modo más simple. Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de hasta 10 niveles, por lo que es un poco más larga la anidación de foreach que estoy haciendo, pero para que vean que no es nada práctico copio solo 5.

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <li class="mb-2"><a href="{{ route('categorias.show', [$shop, $category]) }}">{{ $category -> name }}</a></li>

    @if ( $category -> subcategories )
        @foreach ($category -> subcategories as $subcategory)
            <li class="mb-2"><a href="{{ route('categorias.show', [$shop, $subcategory]) }}">→ {{ $subcategory -> name }}</a></li>

            @if ( $subcategory -> subcategories )
                @foreach ($subcategory -> subcategories as $subcategory2)
                    <li class="mb-2"><a href="{{ route('categorias.show', [$shop, $subcategory2]) }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→ {{ $subcategory2 -> name }}</a></li>

                    @if ( $subcategory2 -> subcategories )
                        @foreach ($subcategory2 -> subcategories as $subcategory3)
                            <li class="mb-2"><a href="{{ route('categorias.show', [$shop, $subcategory3]) }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→ {{ $subcategory3 -> name }}</a></li>

                            @if ( $subcategory3 -> subcategories )
                                @foreach ($subcategory3 -> subcategories as $subcategory4)
                                    <li class="mb-2"><a href="{{ route('categorias.show', [$shop, $subcategory4]) }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→ {{ $subcategory4 -> name }}</a></li>

                                @endforeach
                            @endif

                        @endforeach
                    @endif

                @endforeach
            @endif

        @endforeach
    @endif

@endforeach
```

¿Alguien que conozca la fórmula mágica para hacerlo sencillo?
Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías hacer que el modelo tenga referencia a sí mismo

En tu modelo `Category` podrías tener un método para identificar categorías padre y categorías hijo (Sub categorías)

```
class Category extends Model {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Luego puedes tener un método recursivo para obtener las sub categorías de cualquier categoría (Por si quieres obtener todos los decendientes de una sola vez)

```
// Obtiene todos los decendientes
public function descendants()
{
   return $this->children()->with('descendants');
}
```

Para obtener una categoría con todos las sub categorías (Descendientes) puedes hacer esto

```
$categories = Category::with('descendants')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

---

**Si sólo te intereza reducir el número de `@foreach` en tu vista, revisa a partir de aquí**

En tu vista, para reducir todos los `@foreach` puedes utilizar vistas parciales, es decir, creas un archivo blade (`partials/category.blade.php`) con la información que deséas mostrar para cada elemento

Por ejemplo (Intenté utilizar el formato de `<li>` que usas para tus categorías).

Archivo `partials/category.blade.php`

```
<li class="mb-2"><a href="{{ route('categorias.show', [$shop, $category]) }}">{{ $category -> name }}</a></li>
    @if (count($category->descendants > 0)
        @foreach ($category->descendants as $category)
            @include('partials.category', $category)
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Y en tu archivo `blade` donde muestras las categorías utilizas `@each`

```
@each('partials.category', $categories, 'category')
```

Donde los argumentos de `@each` son:

```
@each('vista-parcial-a-mostrar', $data, 'nombrevariable','vista-parcial-opcional')
```

El primer argumento es el archivo blade de la vista parcial que quieres mostrar para cada categoría `partials/category.blade.php`. El segundo argumento es la variable iterable, es decir, `$categories`. El tercer argumento es el nombre de la variable que se va a utilizar para iterar. Ejemplo, en `foreach ($categories as $category)` tienes tu variable iterable `$categories` y tu variable para iterar `$category` entonces utilizamos `$category` pero le quitamos el `$`. El cuarto argumento es opcional y sirve para agregar una segunda vista parcial en caso de que el segundo argumento esté vacío, es decir, en caso de que no haya sub categorías, en el ejemplo anterior no lo incluí.

Si deseas más información sobre las vistas parciales puedes revisar [este tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-blade-recursive-partials/)

**Nota:** La vista parcial la hice utilizando como referencia tus `@foreach` pero podría no funcionar directamente, tal vez necesites adaptarla según la información extra que tengas en tu modelo o en tu migración.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya corregí lo del blade, no me dí cuenta del problema de N+1

Comment: Excelente!! muchas gracias! Ya lo acomodé yo la parte estética y quedó genial.